# Filter Blank cells only in an array of cells and set new values to them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to select the blank cells only in Column no. 22 and if found put a Date & Timestamp in that cell.

```
function () {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var timestamp = sheet.getRange(2,22,lastrow-1).getValues();
    var blank = timestamp.filter(function(blanks){return blanks =='';});

    for (var i = 0; i < blank.length ; i++ )
         blank.setValue(new Date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you one of the possible solutions. Feel free to change the timestamp format.

The high-level idea here is to build the data for all the cells in the range and set them at once (for performance purposes).

```
function fillTimestamp() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(2,22,lastrow-1);
    var values = targetRange.getValues();
    
    var data = [];

    for (var row in values) {
      for (var col in values[row]) {    
        if(values[row][col] == ''){
          data.push([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z')]);
        }
        else{
          data.push([values[row][col]])
        }
      }
    }

    targetRange.setValues(data);
}
```